# lxml and request scrape javascript table

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml

The purpose of this code is to scrape a table from a java script web page.

The page  = https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/unemployment-rate-301

PS: I did not use selenium because it is extremely slow and I prefer request and lxml
Here is the code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}
link = 'https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/unemployment-rate-301'
url = link.strip()
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
table = tree.xpath('//*[@id="eventTabDiv_history_0"]')
for table in table:
    table = table.text
    print(table)
```

the problem is that it did not print any thing no table and no error

Comment: If the content displayed on the page is as a result of javascript execution you’ll either have to use a browser simulator like Selenium because it will execute the javascript, or discover the HTTP requests being made by the javascript and replicate those with `reuests`.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that table element doesn't have any text itself. To get texts of its children function `text_content()` can be used:

```
for table in table:
    table = table.text_content()
    print(table)
```